# How to solve this equation using java?

Tags: java

**= √12 × (1/1x3<sup>0</sup> - 1/3x3<sup>1</sup> +  1/5x3<sup>2</sup> - 1/7x3<sup>3</sup> +........)**

I am trying to solve this equation using java but I do not know how to make subtract when the power is odd.

```
public static double calculatePiInnitial(int i){
     double sum = 0;
     for (int n=0; n<=i;n++){
         for(int k = 1; k<=k; k =+ 2) {
             if (n % 2 == 0)
                 sum += 1/k*Math.pow(3, n);
             else
                 sum += -1/k* Math.pow(3, n);
         }



     }
    System.out.println(sum);
    final double SQRT_12 = Math.sqrt(12)  ;
    double Pi =  SQRT_12 * sum;
    return Pi ;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: You're not *solving* anything here. You're just computing a value.

Comment: You have a problem with the integer division `1/k`. And the power should be `n`, not `i`.

Comment: for (int n=0; n<=i;n++){
             for(int k = 1; k<=k; k =+ 2)
                 if (n % 2 == 0)
                     sum += 1/k*Math.pow(3, n);
                 else
                     sum += -1/k* Math.pow(3, n);

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the method that you have posted.

Firstly, you are attempting to initialize a variable in out update expression `n++ int k=0`, which is not valid syntax.
Even if the syntax allowed this, the update expression in not executed until after the body of the `for` loop, which means that `k` would not be accessible within the loop.

You should instead declare `k` together with `n` in you initialize expression. (also `k` should be initialized as `1` not `0`)

Secondly, you are using `i` as the exponent when it should be `n`.

With these changes, you method becomes:

```
 public static double calculatePiInnitial(int i){

 double sum = 0;
 for (int n=0, k = 1; n<=i; n++, k+=2){
    if(n%2 == 0)
        sum += 1/(k * Math.pow(3,n));
    else
        sum -= 1/(k * Math.pow(3,n));
 }
System.out.println(sum);
final double SQRT_12 = Math.sqrt(12)  ;
double Pi =  SQRT_12 * sum;
return Pi ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in two for loops , this is how it can be done. Here the inner for loop iterates only once.

```
public static double calculatePiInitial(int i){
        double sum = 0;
        for (int n=0; n<=i;n++){
            for(int k = n*2+1; k < n*2+2; k++) {
                if (n % 2 == 0)
                    sum += 1/(k*Math.pow(3, n));
                else
                    sum += -1/(k* Math.pow(3, n));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        final double SQRT_12 = Math.sqrt(12)  ;
        double Pi =  SQRT_12 * sum;
        return Pi ;
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I want to iterate the second for loop only one time every time. How can I do that?        double sum = 0;
        for (int n=0; n<=i;n++){
            for(int k = 1; k<=i;k =+ 2) {
                if (n % 2 == 0)
                    sum += 1/k*Math.pow(3, n);
                else
                    sum += -1/k* Math.pow(3, n);

            }

        }

Comment: @NSD Whats the point of using a for loop if you only want to iterate only one time.

Comment: I want the second for loop to iterate only one time for every iteration. So the result can be like this 1/1x3^0 - 1/3x3^1 + 1/5x3^2 - 1/7x3^3.....