# How to iterate for loop only one time in a nested loop in java?

Tags: java, math, pi

```
calculatePiInnitial(4)
public static double calculatePiInnitial(int i){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int n=0; n<=i;n++){
        for(int k = 1; k<=i;k =+ 2) {
            if (n % 2 == 0)
                sum += 1/k*Math.pow(3, n);
            else
                sum += -1/k* Math.pow(3, n);

        }

    }
```

Like here I want the second for loop to iterate only one time for every iteration.
So the result can be like this
1 - 1/9 + 1/135 - 1/184 .....

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955269/how-to-solve-this-equation-using-java

Comment: `for (int n = 0, k = 1; n <= i; i++, k += 2)`

Answer (score 0):

What if you add a break statement at the very end of the second for loop?

```
calculatePiInnitial(4)
public static double calculatePiInnitial(int i){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int n=0; n<=i;n++){
        for(int k = 1; k<=i;k =+ 2) {
            if (n % 2 == 0)
                sum += 1/k*Math.pow(3, n);
            else
                sum += -1/k* Math.pow(3, n);
            break;    
        }

    }
```

Or you can also do this...
Only iterate until `K = 2`, and increment K by 1 after each iteration

```
calculatePiInnitial(4)
public static double calculatePiInnitial(int i){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int n=0; n<=i;n++){
        for(int k = 1; k<=2;k ++) {
            if (n % 2 == 0)
                sum += 1/k*Math.pow(3, n);
            else
                sum += -1/k* Math.pow(3, n);

        }

    }
```